# role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Working with Oracle 11g and 2 different computers running Windows 10 (yuck)

I was trying to import a schema via network_link.

I am getting some errors that some grants are missing

Here is the error:(one of them, the other errors are similar)

```
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE" TO "GEO127" WITH ADMIN OPTION
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'APEX_GRANTS_FOR_NEW_USERS_ROLE' does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "APEX_GRANTS_FOR_NEW_USERS_ROLE" TO "GEO127" WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

---

My question is...I know I can "create role" but how do I know which privileges belong to that role?

I did try to add the role but it is not in the catalog?

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
grant apex_administrator_read_role to geo127
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01919: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist
01919. 00000 -  "role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    Role by that name does not exist.
*Action:   Verify you are using the correct role name.
```

Also, I looked at the "source" database and the 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does exist, I guess I would like to know how to duplicate this on the "target"

---

```
C:\Users\COMPUTER>impdp geo127/******** directory=data_pump_dir network_link=legacy remap_schema=geo:geo127

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Starting "GEO127"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01":  geo127/******** directory=data_pump_dir network_link=legacy remap_schema=geo:geo127
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 882.8 MB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-31684: Object type USER:"GEO127" already exists
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE" TO "GEO127" WITH ADMIN OPTION
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'APEX_GRANTS_FOR_NEW_USERS_ROLE' does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "APEX_GRANTS_FOR_NEW_USERS_ROLE" TO "GEO127" WITH ADMIN OPTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
ORA-39083: Object type DEFAULT_ROLE failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist
Failing sql is:
 ALTER USER "GEO127" DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT", "RESOURCE", "DBA", "SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE", "EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE", "DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE", "EXP_FULL_DATABASE", "IMP_FULL_DATABASE", "LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR", "DBFS_ROLE", "AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE", "AQ_USER_ROLE", "DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE", "DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE", "ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK", "GATHER_SYSTEM_STATIST
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
ORA-31684: Object type SEQUENCE:"GEO127"."HIER_SEQ" already exists
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GEO127"."NOCOUNTRY" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'GEOGRAPHIC' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "GEO127"."NOCOUNTRY" ("GEONAMEID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "ASCIINAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "LATITUDE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "LONGITUDE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "FEATURE_CLASS" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "FEATURE_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "CC2" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN1_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN2_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GEO127"."HIERARCHY" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'GEOGRAPHIC' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "GEO127"."HIERARCHY" ("PARENTID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "CHILDID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "HID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEF
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GEO127"."GEONAMES" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'GEOGRAPHIC' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "GEO127"."GEONAMES" ("GEONAMEID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "ASCIINAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "LATITUDE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "LONGITUDE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "FEATURE_CLASS" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "FEATURE_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "CC2" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN1_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN2_CODE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), "ADMIN3_
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"GEO127"."EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_2712" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'GEOGRAPHIC' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "GEO127"."EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_2712" ("PROCESS_ORDER" NUMBER, "DUPLICATE" NUMBER, "DUMP_FILEID" NUMBER, "DUMP_POSITION" NUMBER, "DUMP_LENGTH" NUMBER, "DUMP_ORIG_LENGTH" NUMBER, "DUMP_ALLOCATION" NUMBER, "COMPLETED_ROWS" NUMBER, "ERROR_COUNT" NUMBER, "ELAPSED_TIME" NUMBER, "OBJECT_TYPE_PATH" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), "OBJECT_PATH_SEQNO" NUMBER, "O
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "GEO127"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" completed with 9 error(s)


C:\Users\COMPUTER>
```

---

### -- tried to grant the role

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
grant apex_administrator_read_role to geo127
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01919: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE' does not exist
01919. 00000 -  "role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    Role by that name does not exist.
*Action:   Verify you are using the correct role name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about database reporting related to Apex (**Application Express**) (https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/HTMDB/about-utilizing-database-reporting.htm#HTMDB29893)

> If you are granted the APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE or
>   APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE then you can query across the entire instance,
>   rather than just the workspace your schema user is associated with.
>   You should grant APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE to monitoring users,
>   while APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE should be used for instance
>   administrators, who manage instance parameters, workspaces, and so on.

It seems that there's Apex installed in source database, while it doesn't exist in target database. Therefore, I'd say that you should:

- install Apex in target database
- ignore the error (but user you're importing won't be able to query across the whole instance which is irrelevant as there's no Apex in target database anyway)

**[EDIT, after reading the comment]**

I'm running 11g XE on my laptop. It comes with Apex 4 so I checked whether role that causes problems exists there. Apparently, it does not:

```
SQL> select * From all_users where username like 'APEX%';

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- --------
APEX_040000                            47 29.05.14
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 29.05.14

SQL> select * From dba_roles where role like 'APEX%';

ROLE                           PASSWORD AUTHENTICAT
------------------------------ -------- -----------
APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE        NO       NONE

SQL>
```

See? No `APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_READ_ROLE` in Apex 4.

So, I wouldn't do it in such a dramatic manner as you suggested (reformat hard disk and start over) - it would be way simpler to upgrade to Apex 5.x instead.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  Both computers have Apex installed.  The source computer is running Apex 5, the target computer is running Apex 4, however I am working in Developer SQL.  When I went to the target computer and "edit user" to grant the target user the roles in the error, the roles I need are not on the list.  I am not sure why this is.  I am tempted to reformat the HD in the target and do a fresh re-install of 11g, Apex and Developer.  Do you think that will help?

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thank you for the information.  I will upgrade to Apex 5 and try the export again.